# Java EE alfresco mule

Tags: apache-flex, spring, jakarta-ee, alfresco, mule

Is there any tutorial or a book that shows how to create a Java EE project with the following technologies: flex, spring, hibernate, alfresco and mule?

Comment: You may also want to clairfy some of the technologies on your list.  What is a jee project, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the advices from the comments. Anyway, the following resources might be of interest for you:

- [Mule Alfresco integration](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Mule_Alfresco_Integration)
- [FlexSpaces](http://code.google.com/p/flexspaces/)